# Set Opacity Pie Chart Highcharts

Tags: highcharts, opacity

How can I set the opacity for the fill color in the pie chart? I am using the highcharts js library.  See code below:

```
$(function () { 

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            backgroundColor: 'none',
            type: 'pie',

        },
        title: {
            text: 'Health'
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                fillOpacity: 0.1,
                colors: ['#50B432', '#ED561B', '#DDDF00', '#24CBE5', '#64E572', ],
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],

                ['IE',       26.8],

                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
                ]
        }]
    });
});
```

A bit of a JS newbie, so please be kind.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be kind.  You can specify the color in rgba format with the fourth parameter being the opacity.  See 'Chrome' below:

```
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Browser share',
            data: [
                ['Firefox',   45.0],
                ['IE',       26.8],
                {
                    name: 'Chrome',
                    y: 12.8,
                    sliced: true,
                    selected: true,
                    color: 'rgba(150,100,50,0.1)'
                },
                ['Safari',    8.5],
                ['Opera',     6.2],
                ['Others',   0.7]
            ]
        }]
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/manishie/62VJJ/

Comment: Thank you! This has perfectly addressed my question.

Answer (score -1):

The above solution works fine if you know what color you wish to assign to the slice. But if the color is picked from a palette which is generic, there is no way to give the opacity. It always takes 0. For example:

`Highcharts.chart('container', 
  {colors: [my palette]},
  series:[{
   type: 'pie',
   data: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
)`

In the above case if I set `series: [{fillOpacity: 0.5}]` it is not honored.
The only option I see is that the palette should have the colors in `rgba` format. This may not be possible since my palette is a generic palette. Is there any other way in which I can set the opacity of the slices in a pie chart.